# Porting matlab structure arrays to C#

Tags: c#, matlab, variables, porting

I have a bunch structure arrays like listed below that Id like to port over to C#. This is a part of a big project. How can I easily achieve something like this in C# ? Such as grouping variables ? I know a class will do but to do something like this Id perhaps have to create a number of nested classes ?

```
robot.task.mapBuilding.exploration.isExploring = 0;
robot.task.mapBuilding.exploration.initialiseAreaExploration = 1;
robot.task.mapBuilding.exploration.isInExplorationArea = -1;
robot.task.mapBuilding.exploration.lists.canRequestNewTask = 1;
robot.task.mapBuilding.exploration.lists.requestNewTask = [];
robot.task.mapBuilding.exploration.lists.receivedNewTask = [];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you looking at porting manually or writing some code to do it automatically?

Comment: manually ofcourse. this is a big project with 1000's of lines. would be nice if there was a elegant way of porting it automatically. unfortunately not. im porting so that its compatible with the microsoft robotics platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about matlab, but based on what you have shown above you could have a class library with a `robot.task.mapbuilding` namespace but it would require some classes and nested as you say.
For example an `exploration` class that contains a `lists` class:

```
namespace robot.task.mapBuilding
{
    public class lists
    {
        public lists()
        {
            _canRequestNewTask= true;
        }
        private bool _canRequestNewTask;
        private string _requestNewTask;
        private string _receivedNewTask;
        public bool CanRequestNewTask {get{return _canRequestNewTask;}set{_canRequestNewTask=value;}}
        public string RequestNewTask{get{return _requestNewTask;}set{_requestNewTask=value;}}
        public string ReceivedNewTask {get{return _receivedNewTask;}set{_receivedNewTask=value;}}
    }

    public class exploration
    {
        public exploration()
        {
            isExploring = false;
            initialiseAreaExploration = true;
            isInExplorationArea = -1;
        }
        private bool _isExploring;
        private bool _initialiseAreaExploration;
        private bool _isInExplorationArea;
        private lists _lists;

        public bool IsExploring {get{return _isExploring;} set{_isExploring = value;}}
        public bool InitialiseAreaExploration{get{return _initialiseAreaExploration;}set{_initialiseAreaExploration=value;}}
        public bool IsInExplorationArea {get{return _isInExplorationArea;}set{_isInExplorationArea=value;}}
        public lists Lists {get{return _lists;}set{_lists=value;}}
   }
}
```

**edit**

If you're not bothered about value validation or initialisation on construction then this could be wittled down to:

```
namespace robot.task.mapBuilding
{
    public class lists
    {
        public bool CanRequestNewTask {}
        public string RequestNewTask {}
        public string ReceivedNewTask {}
    }

    public class exploration
    {
        public bool IsExploring {}
        public bool InitialiseAreaExploration {}
        public bool IsInExplorationArea {}
        public lists Lists {}
    }
}
```

Note that I've kept to the property naming convention of starting with capitals, although I haven't done so with the classes (which I suppose I should have done really).

Comment: Thanks chris. do you see any harm in setting the variables public without the gets and sets ??

Comment: No - if you don't wish to perform any actions on them then you could do as my added example.